# Postmates API Unexpected response

Tags: postmates

I make the following cUrl command and didn't get the expected response back.

curl -u 3d458af1-xxxa-xxxx-a4d0-ba07cxx4cxxx: \

-d “dropoff_address=20 McAllister St, San Francisco, CA 94102” \

-d “pickup_address=101 Market St, San Francisco, CA 94105” \

-X POST https://api.postmates.com/v1/customers/cus_LxxxxxxT_yqV/delivery_quotes

Response is below:

```
{
    "kind": "error",
    "code": "unknown",
    "message": "Customer has no partner_detail."
}
```

ANY HELP WILL BE HIGHLY APPRECIATED!

Comment: Please include at least your request to your question and add other details  which help to understand the situation.

Comment: I am using Postman [Chrome App], 

Under Authorization , I selected "Basic Auth" and put the "Test API Key" in the Username

Under Body I added pickup_address and dropoff_address

Comment: So ? @user1486269

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully its more clear now